# bannerview.ad unit is obsolete: use adunitid property instead

Tags: xamarin, admob, google-mobile-ads

I'm trying to archive my iOS app and problem shows to me because of Google Mobile Ads .

bannerview.adunit is obsolete: use adunitid property instead

I'm trying to find solution to it

```
 private BannerView CreateBannerView()
    {
        if (_bannerView != null)
            return _bannerView;

        var origin = new CGPoint(0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Height - AdSizeCons.Banner.Size.Height);

        _bannerView = new BannerView(AdSizeCons.SmartBannerPortrait, origin)
        {
            AdUnitID = Element.AdUnitId,
            RootViewController = GetVisibleViewController()
        };

        _bannerView.LoadRequest(GetRequest());

        return _bannerView;
    }

    private Request GetRequest()
    {
        var request = Request.GetDefaultRequest();
```

Comment: https://github.com/marcojak/MTAdmob#important-for-ios

Comment: works fine , thanks .